# Webcomic about an anthropomorphic television guiding a young child on a journey through a dreamworld

Tags: story-identification, webcomics

The webcomic begins with the television (human body, television for a head) asking the child (I can't remember if it was a boy or girl, I just remember it wasn't very clear until later) if they want to go on an adventure.

The television takes the child into a land of dreams where they run away or battle doubts and fears given form, meet strange creatures that help/hinder them, and pay for things with their dreams/imagination.

The head of the anthropomorphic television is an actual crt tv with dials (and antennas?). The screen is constantly showing static patterns and SMPTE color bars, and I think at one point the television plays some form of movie for the young child to watch.

The television always seems to have some sort of colorful liquid leaking from its face/screen. The child is incredibly naive, trusting almost anything despite constant warnings from the television that things are not always as they seem, and absolutely nothing should ever be trusted.

I was first introduced to the webcomic last year. I don't remember exactly when. But since then, I haven't been able to find it again. The Webcomic had 1 or 2 chapters and appeared to have been running for a couple months. This was sometime last year, so hopefully the author has added more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[The Property of Hate](https://jolleycomics.com/TPoH/The_Hook/)?

Description from [TVTropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Webcomic/ThePropertyOfHate):
The Property of Hate is a webcomic by Sarah Jolley (aka Modmad aka Fred aka Albionhands) that began publication in early 2012 and usually updates on Sundays.

A young girl is suddenly awoken by a strange man who refers to himself simply as RGB. He is formal in speech and odd in the head, or in the television set where his head should be. He asks her if she would like to become a hero, and though she answers with gusto, she doesn't have any knowledge of what will be expected of her as she leaves her home for a world in the skies.

The journey across the clouds takes her to a world badly in need of a hero, where lies and fears are very real and very dangerous. The hero's courage helps her survive her first encounter with fear itself, but her very young age — and RGB's refusal to explain anything — make it a difficult and dangerous journey for her.

First panel:
[image]

Comment: Yes! This is it! Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Edit:  not the answer, unfortunately, but a solid webcomic for sure.

Was it [Rice Boy](http://www.rice-boy.com/see/)?  Certainly has your anthropomorphic TV, an extremely naive adventurer, and a dreamlike world.

[image]

Comment: +1 I am guessing it's not *Rice Boy* based on the last part of the question, but The One Electronic is *precisely* where my mind went also. :)

Comment: Wow. I didn't realize how many characters are anthropomorphized televisions. Sadly, this is not the webcomic that I am trying to remember. The television head from mine is a rectangular crt television with dials. The screen is constantly showing static patterns and SMPTE color bars, and I think at one point the television plays some form of movie for the young child to watch. I'll add this information to the question.

Comment: And I am now reading Rice Boy. It's fascinating, and definitely has some similarities to what I was remembering, but it isn't the same. It is very likely the author of the webcomic I am trying to find was influenced by Rice Boy. 
Thank you for introducing me to this webcomic.